# Copy a pointer's reference to another pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I have a struct and a pointer to a certain instance of it,
now I want to make a new pointer point to that instance with no dependency to the first pointer so that when I change the first pointer, the second still points to that instance.
here is a code snippet:

```
struct
{
    int some;
    int variables;
} someStruct;

someStruct *a=malloc(sizeof(someStruct));
a->some=10;
a->variables=20;
someStruct *b;
b=a;
a=NULL;
Thread1
{
    /// some operations on "b"
    free(b);
}

Thread2
{
    free(a);
}
```

In my program, b also becomes NULL, how can I avoid that?

Comment: it there another type named sommStruct ?

Comment: Your code is correct (apart from the struct typo) but you'll have to use `b` to `free` the memory.

Comment: Post the complete code. There's no reason `b` should be `NULL` with the code you showed.

Comment: Thie posted code is not the real code that shows the problem. For example, `someStrct` is not a type, but a variable. Please copy and paste the real code here.

Comment: well the real code is very complicated with threads and stuff, when doing this solution the problem seemed to come from this part, a "segmentation fault" appeared.

Comment: I was using what @Mike Minaev suggested below and was working, but this code gets executed a lot so it give an unnecessary overheat

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem in a minimal code example? That in itself may help you find the problem (for example, you may realize that it's completely somewhere else).

Comment: I edited my code to something closer to my program

Comment: What's point in minimal example here, if language spec is very clear about this? It will not be as the question states. Problem is elsewhere. If your debugger supports watchpoints - set one to `&b` and watch where it changes.

Comment: I'm being a bit demanding here, but can you post a full, (minimal), *compilable* code in which you are sure the problem arise? :D

Comment: Shoudln't the struct type declaration be: `typedef struct
{
    int some;
    int variables;
} someStruct;`? The keyword `typedef`is missing, making it a variable declaration instead.

Answer (score 0):

b will not become NULL in the following:

```
sommStruct *b;
b=a;
a=NULL;
```

Comment: @1336087 I just answered the qs, the program snippet shown has no flaw, copying a pointer by value and then making the source to NULL will not have a effect on the copy made earlier, right? then, why downvote?

Comment: I did, sorry for not commenting. I'm fairly new to SO so maybe it wasn't the best thing to do. Shouldn't an answer basically saying "your question is invalid" be a comment instead?